# Need to understand CSS3 background shorthand property

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand following CSS3 background shorthand property and need to break it down in individual properties. I am not able to figure out what are actual properties for values `98%` and `center` in below shorthand property

```
background: url(../images/icon-error-small.png) no-repeat scroll 98% center #FFFFFF
```

Comment: You can start with the [W3C wiki documentation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background) on it. Also, this is not a CSS3-specific property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorthand notation for background properties:

```
background:  [background-image] [background-repeat] [background-attachment]  [background-position] [background-color];
```

On breaking:

```
background-image: url(../images/icon-error-small.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: 98% center;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
```

Answer (score 4):

The break down goes like

`background: url(../images/icon-error-small.png)` - Image URL

`no-repeat` - Background Repeat

`scroll` - Background Attachment

`98% center` - Background Position (X-98%, Y-center)

`#FFFFFF` - Fall Back Color

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet when you have questions like this is to go straight to the source. It's even got a section for shorthand which, I believe, will answer your question and help understand the other aspects about shorthand and CSS3 that may be confusing to you.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/

```
 <bg-layer> = <bg-image> || <position> [ / <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box>{1,2}
```

Comment: Note that although keeping the properties in this order is strongly recommended, don't assume that CSS writers adheres so strictly to the standards! Therefore, most browsers don't mind if the order is different. They just go by "does it start with `url`, if so it's an image. Does it start with any of the `repeat` keywords, etc.